# KSQL Streams Array of Struct object in Where Clause

Tags: ksqldb

I have written KSQL query to filter records whose country code is US.Below query is working fine however I have hardcoded the ADDRESSES[0], but in the where clause i dont want to hardcode [0] position

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerStream 
WHERE uniqueIdentity->identityType = 'Passport' 
and ADDRESSES[0]->COUNTRYCODE='US';
```

I should be able to fetch all the customers whose country code ='US' , below is sample message in the stream

```
{
  "CUSTOMERID": "Cust01",
  "FIRSTNAME": "ABC",
  "LASTNAME": "DEF",
  "GENDER": "NA",
  "DATEOFBIRTH": 1706425538817,
  "ADDRESSES": [
    {
      "ADDRESSTYPE": "Home",
      "HOUSENUMBER": "123",
      "POSTALCODE": "172612",
      "COUNTRYCODE": "UK"
    },
    {
      "ADDRESSTYPE": "Office",
      "HOUSENUMBER": "123",
      "POSTALCODE": "562317",
      "COUNTRYCODE": "US"
    }
  ],
  "UNIQUEIDENTITY": {
    "IDENTITYTYPE": "AWERT",
    "IDENTITYNUMBER": "G5PIX",
    "EXPIRYDATE": 1705600302337
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid, that ksqldb does not support this type of nested where statements.
What might work here is somehow flattering and then use flattered fields in where statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).